# Get a double to store a value C++

Tags: c++

Just wanted to know what is wrong with this. Double in is suppose to be set to 50 if it is NULL. Then after it is set to 50 it gets subtracted with the user input of double bbet with the analyze(). But after it loops it self it still thinks double in is NULL. Can any one point me in the right direction to get in to remember the value it subtracted its self with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


class Bet
{
public:
void set_stack(double n);
void set_bet(double n);
void analyze();
double get_stack();
double get_bet();

private:
double pCount;
double bet;
};

void Bet::analyze()
{
double p = pCount;
double b = bet;
double z = p - b;

pCount = z ;
}

void Bet::set_bet(double n)
{
double z = n;
bet = z;

}
double Bet::get_bet()
{
return bet;
}


void Bet::set_stack(double n)
{

double z = n;

pCount = z;
}


double Bet::get_stack()
{
double p = pCount;
double b = bet;


double z = p - b;

return z;
}
double bbet;
double in ;
double* inV;

int main()
{


bool con = true;
while(con){
double start = 50;


if(*inV == NULL){
in = start;}



Bet rr;
rr.set_stack(in);


cout << "Enter min 1 Bet: ";
cin >> bbet;

rr.set_bet(bbet);


double newStack = rr.get_stack();

cout << "Stack: " << newStack << endl;
cout << "Bet: " << bbet << endl;
inV = &in;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `double` isn't supposed to be `NULL`.

Comment: What would be the best strategy to get it to record the value without using a vector or array?

Comment: "What would be the best strategy to get it to record the value without using a vector or array?"  What value?  The size of each bet?  If you don't want to use a vector or array, try a `std::list`.  What's actually best depends on how you need to look up the values later - for instance, a multiset could facilitate finding bets of a particular monetary value, but would lose the chronological ordering...

Comment: Is there a way to get a pointer to store one value each time?

Answer (score 0):

You want `if (inV == NULL)` rather than `if (*inV == NULL)`.